# Can you change Unity's default script template for a single project?

Tags: unity

Can you change Unity's default script template **for a single project**?

[Here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/22605/how-can-you-modify-the-default-script-templates-wh.html) it's explained how to do that globally and it's fine, I wonder if you can do it on a per-project basis.

I mean, I'd bet you can't or I would have been able to find it, but maybe I missed something, or there's a plugin, who knows...

Comment: any luck with a better solution, im interested in this one still

Comment: @Joe it's been just 1 month, I wouldn't hold my breath.

Answer (score 3):

unfortunately in my travels i have not yet found a way to do this, and afaik i haven't seen an add-on to specifically do this either.

**[what i have found is an interesting answer here...](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/371094/custom-script-template-per-project.html)** of a possibly useful alternative solution...  there the op goes into modifying the editor with some custom scripts to enhance the "create script" menu options, essentially to include your new script templates as options

hope this helps